# vba to compare 2 pairs of columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this workbook, I have column "A" through "D". Column "A" and "B" have one set of data and "C" and "D" have the other. I need to compare A and C as well as B and D. If there is duplicates then they should be deleted. There are also over 1k rows. Can't give an exact picture due to the level of security of the data.

The action column can be left out.

[image]

Comment: Use `MIN(Ax,Cx)` instead of `Ax` and `MAX(Ax,Cx)` instead of `Cx` (and the same for B/D column) in formula () which detects duplicating. I.e. Search duplicates by `CONCATENATE(MIN(Ax,Cx),MIN(Bx,Dx),MAX(Ax,Cx),MAX(Bx,Bx))` (additional helper column may be used for to simplify the process). If errorneous duplicates occured (`'aa'+'b' == 'a'+'ab'`) then add some non-textual char (for example, `CHAR(9)`) between field adresses in the formula.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It works when I have numbers within the excel spreadsheet, but it is all text, the issue I have been running into is the formulas don't want to reference the cell. It also needs to be VBA as I would like to have it automatically delete the duplicates, if that's possible.

Comment: Use `IF(Ax>Cx,Cx,Ax)` instead of MIN() and backward for MAX, what a problem?

Comment: The formula I have is =CONCATENATE(IF(A2>C2,C2,A2),IF(B2>D2, D2,B2),IF(A2<C2,C2,A2),IF(B2<D2, D2,B2)). When using it across multiple cells it references the correct cell, but outputs the incorrect data. I'm not sure the formula I'm using is the formula you're proposing.

Comment: *it references the correct cell, but outputs the incorrect data.* It is too strange. Show screenshot with correct and incorrect data. Post its source CSV (safe for importing) into the question. Share source file if possible (via GoogleSheets, for example).

Comment: For some reason it works in google sheets, but not on microsoft excel. I can show what the result is in google sheets and what is shown in excel. Here's the link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zQYVEtqZLDI6cWI17KO1vuUv2ZKksbcbk2J2NNsvvPc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please compare the formula which you have entered and the formula which is provided by me and then its edited variant created by you, char by char... in your published file I see `=` operators which are absent in the needed formula.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not required.

I would copy all of the data to a new sheet where all the countries are in one column and the names in the other.

Once all the data is in one place then you can use `Data > Remove Duplicates` function to automatically strip the duplicate data.